# 2013 Microsoft Excel Table Filters Shortcut

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to know how to input multiple entries into the search field when you have a list formatted as a table or a pivot table. I am open to any feasible solutions.  The list changes daily and the filter list changes almost as frequently.  How can I do a quick "copy and paste" of search items and plug them into the filter so only that data appears. I will include a small example but the lists can be thousands of lines long and the search filters can be hundreds of separate numbers.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5nja.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7WM1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp4u9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Edit - I realized you stated you may be working with hundreds of criteria. My original answer would only be effective for a few criteria. I've updated the code below, but images may still reference the old VBA.

You can do this with a VBA module, then even create a button to click that will filter based on the values you input in certain cells. You'll want to have the developer tab in the ribbon if you don't have it displayed already. [See here for how to show it.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/show-the-developer-tab-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45)

First, determine which cells will hold your criteria for filtering. In your first picture, you have those in F3-F5. That's fine, but when the range is filtered, those cells may become hidden. For the sake of this demo, I put the range in an area that won't disappear when I filter.

[image]

Next, Press Alt+F11 to open the VBA editor, then create "New Module" by selecting it from the drop down show here:
[image]

In the new module window that appears, enter the following code (EDITED - I realized you are potentially dealing with hundreds of criteria):

```
    Sub MultiSelectFilter()
Dim v As Variant

v = Split(Join(Application.Transpose(Range("A11:A13"))))
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Select
    Range("A1").AutoFilter
    Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=v, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Here's how this works:
First, we tell Excel that A11:A13 are numbers we want to look for. That's what the Dim v As Variant line does.

Then we tell excel what those values are. In my case, A11 through A13. you can add or subtract as many search criteria as you want.

Next we tell excel what range we want to filter. Select the sheet first, then tell it what range to filter (in this case, A1 is the column we'll filter). Then we tell the AutoFilter function what values to look for with `Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=v, Operator:=xlFilterValues`.

Now, when you enter values, you can run the MultiSelectFilter macro from the developer tab under "Macros"

[image]

And it filters the range:

[image]

To take it one step further, and make it a bit more user friendly, you can assign the macro to a button. Add a button under the "Insert" section on the developer tab, then select the MultiSelectFilter macro.
[image]

[image]

[image]

If you're new to VBA, this is a great project to get started on! Hope this helps.